# What is the relationship between Vanna and Gamma?

Tags: options, option-pricing, greeks, mathematics

I'm trying to build a crude model for the effects of delta hedging on major indices like the S&P 500.  My background is more in pure mathematics so a lot of this stuff is new to me.  That said I would like to know if there is a function $f$ such that $vanna=f(gamma)$, where these greeks are from the black-scholes equation.  I would also appreciate it if someone pointed me to some good research papers that cover equity index gamma and vanna modeling.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for anything specific in regards to research papers that cover equity index gamma and vanna modeling?

Comment: I'll take what I can get but I'm especially interested in how gamma and vanna play off of each other.  I.e. gamma increases which suppresses volatility or volatility increases which reduces gamma

Comment: You should rather write the standard infinitesimal P&L of a delta-hedged option in a model where the volatility is stochastic and and develop that P&L at correct order (usually at order 2 in $\delta S$ and order 1 in $\delta V$) to make the vanna (and the gamma) appear and then look for breakevens.